# JQuery DataTables Add class to first row in initComplete

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)
I want to select First row of my table and add "DTTT_selected" class to first row .

I have successfully select the first row, but when I add class it adds "DTTT_selected" to all Rows instead of first selected row.

The Code is :-

```
table = $('#resultTable').DataTable({
aaSorting: [],
ajax: {...},
columnDefs: [...],
initComplete: function () {
    console.log('DataTables has finished its initialisation.');
    var api = this.api();
    var CurrentRow = api.row({ order: 'current' }, 0);
    CurrentRow.select(); //Working Fine
    CurrentRow.$('tr').addClass('DTTT_selected'); // Results all Rows get class DTTT_selected
    }
  }
});
```

Can Some one help me how can I do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: try this CurrentRow.$('tr:eq(0)').addClass('DTTT_selected');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
CurrentRow.$('tr:first').addClass('DTTT_selected');
```